# While Loop in Crystal 'More than maximum' when printing Pallet labels

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to get pallet tickets printed. I have a stored field {Paperdetails.TotalPalletCount} that is the total number of pallets, ie the number of labels I need.

I have a loop

```
LOCAL NUMBERVAR i :=1;
WHILE i < {Paperdetails.TotalPalletCount}
DO
(i = i+1)
```

but I get the error

> A loop was evaluated more than the max number of time allowed

Any help appreciated
Ewan

Comment: I have the formula placed in the group header.

Answer (score 0):

The last line is not assigning a new value to `i` but is comparing it to `i+1`.

Just change the last line as follows (notice the colon `:`)

```
(i := i+1)
```

It should also be noted that loops in Crystal Reports may be evaluated a maximum of 100'000 times.

Comment: Thanks @matsnow. At least I'm now not getting the error. However all I get is True, even when it's not i.e. if i = 1 and TotalPalletCount = 32, I am still only getting record. I'm new to looping

Comment: If you want to print the label x-times but only have one record, then this can't be achieved by just writing a loop inside a formula.
Please mark this question as answered and create a new question with the information about what **exactly** you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.